# Is it possible to make a QLabel Pixmap image appear in a circle using stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have an image with no borders. I am displaying these images using QLabel and they have and they a square boundary. I wanted to know if it possible to display these images in a circular boundary. In short is it possible to make the boundary of QLabel circular. I want to achieve something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mask to modify the shape of your widget:

```
QPixmap pix( "pathToImage.png" );
QLabel label;
label.setPixamp( pix );
label.setMask( pix.mask() );
```

Your `QLabel` will have the same shape than your image.